# How do I get the name of the wifi network I'm connected to?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, command-line

I know how to find it out [in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740932/getting-osx-connected-wi-fi-network-name), but I need to do this in a shell script.

(I could compile and install one of the example programs given in the link, but surely there is already a command line program installed that will give me this information?)

I have MacOS X Yosemite, 10.10.2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
/Sy*/L*/Priv*/Apple8*/V*/C*/R*/airport -I | awk '/ SSID:/ {print $2}'
```

This uses the airport CLI, with the `-I` flag to show information and filter using awk for just the SSID shows the name of the network.

Comment: If the SSID includes spaces, you will need something like `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk -F:  '($1 ~ "^ *SSID$"){print $2}' | cut -c 2-` instead.

Comment: `sed`-based approach to return SSIDs with spaces:
`/Sy*/L*/Priv*/Apple8*/V*/C*/R*/airport -I | sed -n "s/^.*SSID: \(.*\)$/\1/p"`

Comment: it just returns: `AirPort: Off`

Answer (score 4):

Great answer here by grg, but just wanted to add this option in case it is useful for someone to extract the SSID and only the SSID:

`/Sy*/L*/Priv*/Apple8*/V*/C*/R*/airport -I | grep -w SSID | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: I can confirm that the grep/awk pipeline works. But at least for me, on Mojave 10.14.2, `airport` is not in my `/usr/local/sbin` nor anywhere else on my $PATH.

Comment: It looks like this was either removed as of Mojave (it is not present in Catalina or Big Sur either), or was something specific to my system. I removed this from my answer...

Comment: `grep SSID | grep -v BSSID | awk …` looks strange, isn‘t there an easier way?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, `grep -w` will work, and is cleaner. Changed...